# Accordion panel is opened but, Content of first tab is empty

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have an accordion Panel with Dynamic=true. IT is a list of students showing.
There are two issues. Accordion works fine In Fire fox browser, but the content of first tab is blank, and remaining tab has all the contents.

The same accordion panel doesnot work in IE8. Tabs are not toggalable in IE8.

```
<p:accordionPanel  value="#{testBean.studests}" var="stud"  dynamic="true"  activeIndex="#{testBean.formBean.id}">  

              <p:tab title="#{stud.name}" id="studId">
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13770951/accordion-panel-appears-open-but-doesnt-show-content.. As per this I have made changes in CSS


.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content-active {
    display: compact;
}

But still There is no change

Comment: solved the problem, I migrated to primefaces 3.5, everything is working fine now